# C++, Assignment to class instance from a function call?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, variable-assignment, copy-constructor

I understand, or at least have an Idea of, why the following code does not work:

```
class Spambar {
    public:
        Spambar() {};
        Spambar(Spambar& sb) {};

        Spambar operator + (Spambar sb) {
            Spambar new_sb;
            return new_sb;
        }
};

int main() {
    Spambar sb1;
    Spambar sb2;
    Spambar sb3 = sb1 + sb2;  // <<< Error: "No matching function for call to ... "
}
```

I guess, the problem is that the copy-constructor expects a reference to a `Spambar` instance. As no reference but a shallow instance is returned, the compilation fails.

So, how do I get that to work?

Comment: The copy constructor, as well as the `operator+`, should really have a `const Spambar&` for an operand.

Comment: And the problem, why it doesn't work, is because it doesn't _do_ anything. Or is this not the real code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `sb1 + sb2` is a temporary; the copy constructor used to initialise `sb3` requires a non-`const` reference; and you can't take a non-`const` reference to a temporary.

You almost certainly want to fix this by changing the constructor's parameter type to `Spambar const &`. While you're at it, you should almost certainly do the same to `operator+`, and also make the operator itself `const`:

```
Spambar(Spambar const &);
Spambar operator + (Spambar const &) const;
```

If you're doing something very strange, and actually want the copy-constructor to modify its argument, then you'll have to either avoid passing temporaries to it, or do some nasty hackery with `mutable` or `const_cast`. In C++11, you would use a move constructor, with parameter type `Spambar &&`, for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your class does not have a copy constructor taking a `const` reference.  Normally, a copy constructor looks like:

```
Spambar(const Spambar&);
```

The form you show is used in only very rare circumstances, and it is probably preventing your code from working.

Comment: Specifically, the _reason_ it doesn't work is that the immediate result of `operator+` is an rvalue, and rvalues cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: Ahhhh right. I remember. :) Anyway, I don't understand what the `const` keyword does when expressing it in "human terms". Is the value returned by the member-function `operator +` constant or why does that work now?

// Edit: Thanks @ildjarn ^^

Comment: Oh, I thought the reason it doesn't work is because it has `{}` for a function body.

Comment: @MrLister : The class has no data members -- what exactly do you think _should_ go in the constructor body?

Comment: @ildjarn Silly me, I hadn't noticed. I was thrown off by the OP's remark about shallow instances.